# Native library not loaded from cordova apk

Tags: java, android, cordova, java-native-interface, cordova-plugins

I'm making a cordova plugin that would be a simple wrapper for a .jar file and its two .so dependencies. I have tried it before in a normal android application with android studio. By copying the native libraries into the jniLibs/armeabi folder and the jar file into libs/ it worked perfectly.

At the cordova plugin I've made the same folder structure and everything is on the same place. In the plugin.xml I have copying the two files into libs/armeabi which is working because if I look into the apk, they are in the "right" folder.

But when I try to use the plugin from the cordova application it throws an UnsatisfiedLinkError when it tries to call the native library:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.ionicframework.*******-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.ionicframework.*******-2/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libjni.so"
W/System.err( 4224):    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:366)
W/System.err( 4224):    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:988)
W/System.err( 4224):    at *******.<clinit>(ComIO.java:407)
W/System.err( 4224):    at *******.<init>(Printer.java:33)
W/System.err( 4224):    at net.terbe.dev.cordova.*******.print(*******.java:54)
W/System.err( 4224):    at *******.cordova.*******.execute(*******.java:42)
W/System.err( 4224):    at org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin.execute(CordovaPlugin.java:98)
W/System.err( 4224):    at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.exec(PluginManager.java:132)
W/System.err( 4224):    at org.apache.cordova.CordovaBridge.jsExec(CordovaBridge.java:57)
W/System.err( 4224):    at org.apache.cordova.engine.SystemExposedJsApi.exec(SystemExposedJsApi.java:41)
W/System.err( 4224):    at com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.nativeDoRunLoopOnce(Native Method)
W/System.err( 4224):    at com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.handleMessage(SystemMessageHandler.java:53)
W/System.err( 4224):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
W/System.err( 4224):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
W/System.err( 4224):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61
```

Where should I copy these libraries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've recently needed to cross-compile a C library for use in a Cordova app, so based on that experience, I've created an [example Cordova plugin](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-hello-c) and corresponding [test app that uses it](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-hello-c-test).

If you look in my [plugin.xml](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-hello-c/blob/master/plugin.xml#L33) you'll see I also copy the `armeabi` library to `/libs/armeabi`, as well as the other libraries for the other architectures.
That plugin is definitely working (you can try it), so hopefully you can use it as a working reference.

Stupid question: you're not copying *only* the `armeabi` library? Because I'm pretty sure most modern Android devices don't support that (ARMv5/ARMv6) and require `armeabi-v7a` to be in `/libs/armeabi-v7a`...

Comment: Thanks. I got only these two .so files from the device manufacturer in a folder called `armeabi` next to the jar. And theye are working from there if I build the test app in Android Studio with the same folder structure.
I'll try to copy them into the other dirs, too. There is a <appname>/lib/arm/ folder mentioned in the exception. Does it mean that it tries to load them from there?

Comment: You were right. I just had to copy the binary into `libs/armeabi-v7a` instead of `libs/armeabi` Thanks for your help!

Comment: This does not work for me as I explain in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45546988/so-library-not-loaded-from-cordova-apk. @Perrier could you please indicate which Cordova version and Android API level you are using? Thanks!