# .so library not loaded from cordova apk

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, .so

I'm developing a Cordova plugin to wrap a third party SDK, which depends on several **.so** files. I declare the native libraries in plugin.xml like this:

```
    <platform name="android">
    <config-file target="res/xml/config.xml" parent="/*">
        <feature name="RfidScanner">
            <param name="android-package" value="org.un.eac.cordova.plugin.rfid.RfidScanner"/>
        </feature>
    </config-file>

    <!-- armeabi .so -->
    <source-file src="lib/android/armeabi/libandroid_060.so" target-dir="libs/armeabi"/>
    <source-file src="lib/android/armeabi/libdevapi.so" target-dir="libs/armeabi"/>
    <source-file src="lib/android/armeabi/libDeviceAPI.so" target-dir="libs/armeabi"/>
    <source-file src="lib/android/armeabi/libFpCore.so" target-dir="libs/armeabi"/>
    <source-file src="lib/android/armeabi/libfxjni.so" target-dir="libs/armeabi"/>
    <source-file src="lib/android/armeabi/libirdaSerialPort.so" target-dir="libs/armeabi"/>
    <source-file src="lib/android/armeabi/libModuleAPI_Android_Arm.so" target-dir="libs/armeabi"/>
    <source-file src="lib/android/armeabi/libNETLH_E.so" target-dir="libs/armeabi"/>
    <source-file src="lib/android/armeabi/libPSAM.so" target-dir="libs/armeabi"/>
    <source-file src="lib/android/armeabi/libSerialPort.so" target-dir="libs/armeabi"/>


    <!-- armeabi-v7a .so -->
    <source-file src="lib/android/armeabi-v7a/libandroid_060.so" target-dir="libs/armeabi-v7a"/>
    <source-file src="lib/android/armeabi-v7a/libdevapi.so" target-dir="libs/armeabi-v7a"/>
    <source-file src="lib/android/armeabi-v7a/libDeviceAPI.so" target-dir="libs/armeabi-v7a"/>
    <source-file src="lib/android/armeabi-v7a/libFpCore.so" target-dir="libs/armeabi-v7a"/>
    <source-file src="lib/android/armeabi-v7a/libfxjni.so" target-dir="libs/armeabi-v7a"/>
    <source-file src="lib/android/armeabi-v7a/libirdaSerialPort.so" target-dir="libs/armeabi-v7a"/>
    <source-file src="lib/android/armeabi-v7a/libModuleAPI_Android_Arm.so" target-dir="libs/armeabi-v7a"/>
    <source-file src="lib/android/armeabi-v7a/libNETLH_E.so" target-dir="libs/armeabi-v7a"/>
    <source-file src="lib/android/armeabi-v7a/libPSAM.so" target-dir="libs/armeabi-v7a"/>
    <source-file src="lib/android/armeabi-v7a/libSerialPort.so" target-dir="libs/armeabi-v7a"/>

    <!-- jars -->
    <source-file src="lib/android/handheldApi.jar" target-dir="libs"/>
    <source-file src="lib/android/DeviceAPI.jar" target-dir="libs"/>
    <source-file src="lib/android/decoderapijni.jar" target-dir="libs"/>
    <source-file src="lib/android/ModuleAPI_Android_2.2.0.0.jar" target-dir="libs"/>

    <source-file src="src/android/RfidScanner.java" target-dir="src/org/un/eac/cordova/plugin/rfid" />

</platform>
```

The generated APK contains the armeabi and armeabi-v7a in the correct location:

[image]

However I get the following error when running the app:

> W/System.err(11480): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.Handheld-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.Handheld-
>   2/lib/arm64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]] couldn't find "libdevapi.so"

I checked also [Native library not loaded from cordova apk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44072520/native-library-not-loaded-from-cordova-apk#) and what I found different from the original post is that the error message shows the following native library folders:

> nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/.../lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]

While mine shows:

> nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/.../lib/arm64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]

Could that difference have anything to do? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I did work on a cordova-plugin which also included native *.so files. If I remember correctly this error only appeard if I did include native libs which were not compiled. I ended up creating a .aar lib containing the .so libs and adding a custom .gradle script which compiled the .aar. I hope this helps helps to track down your error!

Comment: Thanks David for your comment, but I don't get it. so files are already compiled, otherwise they would be .c files. I also checked your cordova-plugin-live-ocr. Do you mean I should use ndk to generate an .aar out of the .so files and include it the same way you do?

Comment: Yes thats what I meant. I think just putting the .so libs into the libs directory is not enough. Somehow cordova projects need the compile step in the gradle extension file.

Comment: Did you ever fix this? Would be amazing if you could update the answer if you did :)

Comment: Sorry @KrishanPatel, we gave up and decided to use a different device whose SDK didn't depend on any .so files